# Excel VBA / Macro to Output in 'DOS' format like unix2dos does

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I have to upload a CSV file to a website and the format is very specific. I can't change this and so need to get my CSV just right.

One of the issues is that the CSV file must be double quoted around every item. Excel doesn't seem to be able to do this, so I am using the following macro.

```
Sub Export_Quoted_CSV()
   ' Dimension all variables.
   Dim DestFile As String
   Dim FileNum As Integer
   Dim ColumnCount As Long
   Dim RowCount As Long

   ' Prompt user for destination file name.
   DestFile = InputBox("Enter the destination filename" _
      & Chr(10) & "(with complete path):", "Quote-Comma Exporter")

   ' Obtain next free file handle number.
   FileNum = FreeFile()

  ' Turn error checking off.
   On Error Resume Next

   ' Attempt to open destination file for output.
   Open DestFile For Output As #FileNum

   ' If an error occurs report it and end.
   If Err <> 0 Then
      MsgBox "Cannot open filename " & DestFile
      End
   End If

   ' Turn error checking on.
   On Error GoTo 0

   ' Loop for each row in selection.
   For RowCount = 1 To Selection.Rows.Count

   ' Loop for each column in selection.
      For ColumnCount = 1 To Selection.Columns.Count

        ' Write current cell's text to file with quotation marks.
         Print #FileNum, """" & Selection.Cells(RowCount, _
            ColumnCount).Text & """";

         ' Check if cell is in last column.
         If ColumnCount = Selection.Columns.Count Then
            ' If so, then write a blank line.
            Print #FileNum,
         Else
            ' Otherwise, write a comma.
            Print #FileNum, ",";
         End If
      ' Start next iteration of ColumnCount loop.
      Next ColumnCount
   ' Start next iteration of RowCount loop.
   Next RowCount

   ' Close destination file.
   Close #FileNum
End Sub
```

This gets me 99% there, but I still get an error. When I do a file comparison between a file that works and one that is exported using the above macro, the only difference is this:-

```
file my_file_that_works.CSV: ASCII text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators
file not_working.CSV: ASCII text, with very long lines
```

If I then run unix2dos on the not working CSV it will then work.

I would like to cut out this last stage and have the macro do whatever unix2dos does, any advice?

edit

As requested I have uploaded two example CSV files.
https://filebin.net/fqqam40mlktcvia4
The NOT_WORKING.CSV is what the above macro creates, the WORKING.CSV is what I get when I run it through unix2dos. So I would like to amend my macro to have it incorporate whatever changes unix2dos does. Which I believe is how the end of lines are encoded.

Comment: Upload a sample of both files so we can check the difference

Comment: Thank you for your offer but I'd rather not as they have personal information in them. However, the only difference is listed above.

Comment: In case people are unfamilar with unix2dos this is what it does "unix2dos (sometimes named todos or u2d) is a tool to convert line breaks in a text file from Unix format (Line feed) to DOS format (carriage return + Line feed) and vice versa. When invoked as unix2dos the program will convert a Unix text file to DOS format"

Comment: Please paste as text a sample of original data, in whatever format it starts out as (csv text, excel worksheet, etc) as well as an example of what you want for a final output. There is no need to use **real** data, but please use **realistic** data. Otherwise we are wasting time guessing at what you really need where the problem lies.

Comment: I have now uploaded some examples. Thank you.

Comment: Not related to your Q, but you shouldn't use [`End`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/end-statement) to exit the sub.  Better to use `Exit Sub`, use  `GoTo Cleanup` that closes the files etc

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Export_Quoted_CSV()
   ' Dimension all variables.
   Dim DestFile As String
   Dim FileNum As Integer
   Dim ColumnCount As Long
   Dim RowCount As Long

   ' Prompt user for destination file name.
   DestFile = InputBox("Enter the destination filename" _
      & Chr(10) & "(with complete path):", "Quote-Comma Exporter")

   ' Obtain next free file handle number.
   FileNum = FreeFile()

  ' Turn error checking off.
   On Error Resume Next

   ' Attempt to open destination file for output.
   Open DestFile For Output As #FileNum

   ' If an error occurs report it and end.
   If Err <> 0 Then
      MsgBox "Cannot open filename " & DestFile
      End
   End If
       
   ' Turn error checking on.
   On Error GoTo 0

   ' Loop for each row in selection.
   For RowCount = 1 To Selection.Rows.Count

   ' Loop for each column in selection.
      For ColumnCount = 1 To Selection.Columns.Count

        ' Write current cell's text to file with quotation marks.
         Print #FileNum, """" & Selection.Cells(RowCount, _
            ColumnCount).Text & """";

         ' Check if cell is in last column.
         If ColumnCount = Selection.Columns.Count Then
            ' If so, then write a blank line.
            Print #FileNum, vbCr
         Else
            ' Otherwise, write a comma.
            Print #FileNum, ",";
         End If
      ' Start next iteration of ColumnCount loop.
      Next ColumnCount
   ' Start next iteration of RowCount loop.
   Next RowCount

   ' Close destination file.
   Close #FileNum
End Sub
```

So the only thing that was needed was to add vbCr to one line

```
Print #FileNum, vbCr
```

This is what unix2dos appends to each line to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the next way, please. The code skips the part where the csv path is requested. For testing reasons, I used a fix path and it would be good to do the same. The code should be much faster than your code, using an array and doing all processing in memory:

```
Sub Export_Quoted_CSV()
   Dim DestFile As String, FileNum As Integer, RowCount As Long
   Dim i As Long, arr, arr1D, destFileFold As String, strCsv As String

   GoTo Testing 'skips the part of defining the DestFile:___________
   ' Prompt user for destination file name.
   DestFile = InputBox("Enter the destination filename" _
      & Chr(10) & "(with complete path):", "Quote-Comma Exporter")
Testing: '__________________________________________________________

   DestFile = "C:\Teste VBA Excel\testDOS.csv" 'use here your desired test file full name
   destFileFold = left(DestFile, InStrRev(DestFile, "\")) 'extract the foder to be checked
   
   'check te folder existence:
   If Dir(destFileFold, vbDirectory) = "" Then MsgBox "The file path is incorrect...": Exit Sub
   
   ' Obtain next free file handle number.
   FileNum = FreeFile()

   arr = Selection.Value 'put the selected range in an array
   
   'create the string to be put in the file:
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        arr1D = Application.Index(arr, i, 0) 'create a slice 1D array from the arr row
        strCsv = strCsv & """" & Join(arr1D, """,""") & """" & vbCrLf 'Stop
    Next i
    'The string will end in an extra vbCrLf character(s). 
    'If inconvenient, it is easy to eliminate it...

   'put the processed string in the file
   Open DestFile For Output As #FileNum
        Print #FileNum, strCsv
   Close #FileNum
End Sub
```

I do not know how to test the resulted file, in order to check if it is appropriate for your need. I only tried to put in code what I understand that you need, following your explanations... Please, check the code, the resulted file and send some feedback.

Regarding the `InputBox` to define the `DestFile`, I would suggest you to use a constant keeping the folder to be used (or maybe `ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"`) and the user to only write the file name. Then, it also must be checked if the file already exists and warn in case of existing it. Otherwise, it looks complicated to write the full path. Or use a `Dialog`...

Comment: Thank you for your help. This has now changed the file slighty by adding an extra carriage return. Here is a screenshot of how it did look and the one on the right is with your code. https://ibb.co/pbDSX7b  As you can see before the only difference was "Contents have differences only in line separators" but now there are extra lines.

Comment: @Dan Heaford: I am afraid I do not understand what the application you use compares. In the picture left size there are two files (to be compared, probably). Which is the one accepted by the application you need to use it? The first one (most left position), or the second one? Then, I do not understand where from those "extra lines". Did you try opening it with a text editor? With Notepad, for instance...

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have uploaded two example files to the question, I hope this is clearer.